# Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required

Tags: php

I am working in php project, its giving the error as:

```
Warning:
```

> require_once(ROOT_PATH/lib/confs/Conf.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..\htdocs\GProject\lib\exception\ExceptionHandler.php on line 20
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ROOT_PATH/lib/confs/Conf.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in ..\htdocs\GProject\lib\exception\ExceptionHandler.php on line 20

But in `\ExceptionHandler.php` file, the 20th line is

```
require_once ROOT_PATH . '/lib/confs/Conf.php';
```

And I have the file Conf.php under the `lib/confs/Conf.php` itself, even though I am getting the error.

What may be the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code that defines ROOT_PATH?

Answer (score 7):

I would go through the following assumptions debugging this,

1. The file doesn't exist.
2. The ROOT_PATH is incorrectly set.
3. The current working directory isn't what is expected, so if ROOT_PATH is relative, it's breaking the full path.

If none of the above is the case, I'm not sure.

Some libraries must be installed into a directory that is listed in PHP's library path. In these situations you have a few options:

- Install the library into a directory searched by PHP by default (e.g., /usr/share/php).
- Update the include path using `set_include_path` without overwriting the old path (use `get_include_path` in combination with `PATH_SEPARATOR`).

Answer (score 2):

`ROOT_PATH` is not defined in your script. This should be a defined constant with the value of your root path.

Check it if it is defined or not.

```
if (defined('ROOT_PATH')) { echo 'Defined';} else { echo 'Not defined'; }
```

It is not defined.

If it was defined then your error message will contain the value of defined constant since it contains the constant itself in error.

Define in your script.

```
define('ROOT_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); //an example
```

OR you have forgot to include the configuration file in which these constant are defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just do an echo of the whole path you pass to the require_once function and carefully check if there is something wrong with it :

```
echo ROOT_PATH . "/lib/confs/Conf.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today.  I found the answer.
[PHP Bug #23392](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=23392)

Basically you have to install the Pear OLE extension.

pear install OLE